# How to solve the problem Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I have this error **Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled** when I try to run the `react js` application.

I am trying to increment the value inside a `<span>` when I click a `

Here is the code snippet regarding my work...

```
 import React, {Component} from 'react';

 export default class Test extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      counter: 0
    }
  }

  handleClick = () =>{ //this is where it triggers the error mentioned above
    this.setState((state) => ({counter: state.counter+1}));
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <span>{this.state.counter}</span>
        <input type="button" value={this.props.value}
               onClick={this.handleClick} />
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

But I get this error **Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled**

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to be careful about the meaning of this in JSX callbacks. In JavaScript, class methods are not bound by default. If you forget to bind this.handleClick and pass it to onClick, this will be undefined when the function is actually called so you need to write below code in constructor

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      counter: 0
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
```

Comment: this is not answering the issue about classProperties